What is the mixer doing internally and what ICs does this job
Below is an image of the inner workings of the HB100 microwave sensor, taken from the YouTube video linked below.
The green box shows a "mixer" can someone assist in what IC this is or what IC's could be used for this application (shown in the green box)?
In addition, how does the IC achieve this internally and what is the point of the mixer in RF?


(Image source: YouTube video "HB100 Doppler Radar Module - Circuit and Testing" by BertlDS)

Resources:
Datasheet
Link Thank you D.A.S for this link.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency_mixer

That looks like a passive, single balanced diode mixer. The chip contains two Schottky diodes connected in series.

Firstly, where did the picture come from? You are required on this site to give attribution to the source. Microwave engineering is considered a bit of a ‘black art’ in that everything including wires form a critical part of the circuit. This makes it a speciality. In regards to the mixer, the search term is ‘superheterodyne’ which should yield more than enough information. The mixer multiplies two frequencies and the result is frequency (a + b) and (a - b). The lower frequency is normally used for further processing.

Another link I found is HB100 Microwave Doppler Sensor from the North Texas Microwave Society. It includes some spectrum analyser measurements.
